# Spark Streaming checkpointing + mapWithState + async operations

Tags: apache-spark, asynchronous, spark-streaming, checkpoint

In my Spark Streaming job I use mapWithState which obligates me to enable checkpointing. A job is trigger in each batch by the operation: 
`stream.foreachRDD(rdd.foreachPartition())`

Under this situation the job was checkpoinitng every 10 minutes (batches of 1 minute).

Now, I have changed the output operation to async: 
`stream.foreachRDD(rdd.foreachPartitionAsync())`

But checkpointing is not taking place... any hints? I tried checkpointing the RDD which I map with state, it get checkpointed but does not break the lineage so tasks keeps growing with every batch.